# Using Active Record pattern in CakePHP, and avoiding passing arrays around

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

As my CakePHP 2.4 app gets bigger, I'm noticing I'm passing a lot of arrays around in the model layer. Cake has kinda led me down this path because it returns arrays, not objects, from it's `find` calls. But more and more, it feels like terrible practice.

For example, in my Job model, I've got a method like this:

```
public function durationInSeconds($job) {
    return $job['Job']['estimated_hours'] * 3600; // convert to seconds
}
```

Where as I imagine that using active record patter, it should look more like this:

```
public function durationInSeconds() {
    return $this->data['Job']['estimated_hours'] * 3600; // convert to seconds
}
```

(ie, take no parameter, and assume the current instance represents the Job you want to work with)

Is that second way better?

And if so, how do I use it when, for example, I'm looping through the results of a `find('all')` call? Cake returns an array - do I loop through that array and do a `read` for every single row? (seems a waste to re-fetch the info from the database)

Or should I implement a kind of `setActiveRecord` method that emulates `read`, like this:

```
function setActiveRecord($row){
    $this->id = $row['Job']['id'];
    $this->dtaa = $row;
}
```

Or is there a better way?

EDIT: The `durationInSeconds` method was just a simplest possible example. I know for that particular case, I could use virtual fields. But in other cases I've got methods that are somewhat complex, where virtual fields won't do.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on the issue you need to solve. But if you have to make a call to a function for each result row, perhaps it is necessary to redesign the query taking all the necessary data.

In this case that you have shown, you can use simply a virtual Field on Job model:

```
$this->virtualFields = array(
    'duration_in_seconds' => 'Job.estimated_hours * 3600',
):
```

..and/or you can use a method like this:

```
public function durationInSeconds($id = null) {
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    return $this->field('estimated_hours') * 3600; // convert to seconds
}
```

Comment: The 'durationInSeconds' method was just a simplest possible case, that I used as an example. It other situations, I've got methods with a decent amount of business logic for each row, and virtual fields won't cut it. Sorry, I'll update my question to clarify that.